# PHP and JS in order to manage and draw graphs

Tags: php, javascript, charts, draw, organization

I have a project to draw relationships between different elements determined on a sheet.
When the user has finished making the plan, it can export it to a txt file that contains the links. 
A bit like MS Visio but with only three or four elements draguable.

Does anyone have an idea of ​​this project using web languages ​​(php, js) ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure of your question but if you want to draw graphs using php variables with javascript, then the html5 canvas is probably your best bet in terms or proffessionality with design and implementation.

Only downside is it is javascript only, and the user must have a browser that supports canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Raphael](http://www.raphaeljs.com), you can make your users draw anything you want, export the structure as JSON,for example, and treat it with any language you want

Take a look at this [Raphael example](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) to see an interconnected graph